# how to reduce mysql slow query time for big database

Tags: mysql, database

I have almost 5 gb database on my mysql 5.5 myisam. My os architecture is fedora 64 bit. Now I if I do single query from  the table which holding large data query is being slow for more than 30 sec. Can any one please tell me how can I reduce the slow query? I have 2 gb memory and 6 gb swap.
[updated]
slow log out put is here

```
# Query_time: 19.367274  Lock_time: 0.000109 Rows_sent: 54  Rows_examined: 4263723
SET timestamp=1310052008;
SELECT timestamp FROM nse_data WHERE symbol='NIFTY'AND series='IN' AND timestamp BETWEEN '2011-04-07' AND '2011-07-07' ORDER BY timestamp;
```

Thanks

Comment: We're going to need to see the database schema and the current query

Comment: and the output of EXPLAIN <current query>

Comment: @Ovais Khatri I am sorry I forgot to mention I have updated it it's MyISAM @wonk0 and @Jack Murdoch I have updated the slow query log is it ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to try is to add [indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) for the columns you regularly search/order on.

Answer (score 2):

Every query is very different, but at first glance it seems that this particular query can run fastest with this index:

```
ALTER TABLE `nse_data` ADD INDEX `index_nse_data` (`timestamp` ASC, `symbol` ASC, `series` ASC);
```

Of course, it's just a guess, because I don't know anything about your data :)